# error while trying to sort numbers

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PROGRAMMING_PROBLEM_CONTEST4
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

 Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your first input: ");
String firstinput = S.next();

Arrays.sort(firstinput);


 }
 }
```

i am trying to sort a list of numbers but every time i compile it gives me this error

```
.java:26: error: no suitable method found for sort(String)
 Arrays.sort(firstinput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort a `String`, not a `String[]`. If you want to sort a list of numbers, you have a bit more work:

- Make a loop to read multiple numbers, instead of just one.
- Put them all in an array.
- Now, you can use `Arrays.sort` to sort them.

Answer (score 0):

The string class in java also provides a split method that you could use:

```
String[] myArray = "Hello World".split("");
for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
```

Which outputs "Hello World" each letter on a separate line. You can also split around different symbols. For instance if you wanted your user to be able to input numbers 
with two or more digits you would have to place spaces around your numbers on input. Replacing `"Hello World!".split("");` with 
`"Hello World!".split(" ");` will output "Hello" and "World!".

Another option would be to use the Scanners built in nextInt() method and getting input in a loop until the user specifies he is done entering input with a special symbol.

Comment: You forgot the quotation marks around the second "Hello World!".